# AES256 Implementation

Tags: c#, aes

I coded a little implementation to encrypt and decrypt bytes with AES256 (ECB) in C#. I wanted to know if I can optimize/cleanup my code a bit more, or if it i fine like this:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace AES256
{
    class Program
    {

        private static string getString(byte[] b)
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is just a little message to test AES.");

            byte[] key = { 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
                           1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

            byte[] enc = Encrypt(data, key);
            byte[] dec = Decrypt(enc, key);

            Console.WriteLine("Input : {0}", getString(data));
            Console.WriteLine("Key : {0}", getString(key));
            Console.WriteLine("KeySize : {0}", 256);
            Console.WriteLine("Encrypted : {0}", getString(enc));
            Console.WriteLine("Decrypted : {0}", getString(dec));

            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key)
        {
            using (AesCryptoServiceProvider csp = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                csp.KeySize = 256;
                csp.BlockSize = 128;
                csp.Key = key;
                csp.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                csp.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
                ICryptoTransform encrypter = csp.CreateEncryptor();
                return encrypter.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }

        private static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key)
        {
            using (AesCryptoServiceProvider csp = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                csp.KeySize = 256;
                csp.BlockSize = 128;
                csp.Key = key;
                csp.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                csp.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
                ICryptoTransform decrypter = csp.CreateDecryptor();
                return decrypter.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Note, `ICryptoTransform` also implements `IDisposable`, so your `CreateEncryptor()` and `CreateDecryptor()` calls should be wrapped in `using` blocks as well.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about that ! Good catch, I will fix that !

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code is simple to understand and does what it needs to do. Just some remarks:

- Whenever you use the ECB cipher mode, you *must* justify in written form why you use it. This is because this cipher mode can reveal patterns in your plain text.
- Converting the encrypted bytes to an UTF-8 string doesn't make sense. You should better print them in hex or base64.
- Your code contains duplicates. You could extract that code into a method:

  ```
  private AesCryptoServiceProvider CreateProvider(byte[] key) {
      return new AesCryptoServiceProvider {
          KeySize = 256,
          BlockSize = 128,
          Key = key,
          Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
          Mode = CipherMode.ECB
      };
  }
  ```
- You made the `Encrypt` method public, but `Decode` is private. I don't see a reason for this asymmetry.

Comment: Applied most of the mentioned points! :)

Answer (score 5):

I have just two minor comments to add to the existing review:

> ```
>             csp.KeySize = 256;
> ```

This is completely unnecessary, because when you set `Key` it will automatically update `KeySize`.

> ```
>             csp.BlockSize = 128;
> ```

This is also unnecessary, because AES only supports one block size. However, you could argue that it's future-proofing. I personally would remove it.

Comment: I think the blocksize should not have to be set OR it should use an enum. It gives false hope that I can use 256 when really I can't